# How to wrap this output in quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following command, which gives me 99% of what I want:

```
root@CA2UA5232QPZ:/# tail -3 newtag | awk '{print $1}'
v1.0.20170512.1
v1.0.20170712.1
v1.0.20170712.2
root@CA2UA5232QPZ:/#
```

But I need to tweak it so the output looks like this:

```
'v1.0.20170512.1'
'v1.0.20170712.1'
'v1.0.20170712.2'
```

Answer (score 13):

You could pipe your output to `sed`:

```
tail -3 newtag| awk '{print $1}'| sed "s/^/'/;s/$/'/"
```

Comment: this works but I can't understand the sed pattern you've got going on. can anyone break apart this pattern to explain how it works?

Comment: I'll take a crack, if I'm wrong I'm sure someone will come along to correct me: sed is a command that replaces text, often times regex like in this case. sed in this case is given 2 separate regexs to replace: s/^/'/ and s/$/'/   The first one says essentially says at the start of a string or line, add a single tick. The second says at the end of a line, add a single tick. 
Resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944357/carets-in-regular-expressions + man sed. Beyond my explanation, I recommend reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Delimiters

Answer (score 4):

There's the hideous shell quoting hell of these

```
awk '{print "'"'"'" $1 "'"'"'"}'
awk '{print "'\''" $1 "'\''"}'
```

or use an odd output field separator

```
awk -v OFS="'" '{print "", $1, ""}'
```

but this isn't too bad

```
awk -v q="'" '{print q $1 q}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way, using hexadecimal ASCII code for `'`:

```
tail -3 newtag | awk '{print "\x27" $1 "\x27" }'
```

Comment: Good call. PS: awk print would work better with $0, should the line contain space characters.

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' The code in the question is `tail -3 newtag | awk '{print $1}'` and we know nothing about `newtag`. It's possible the OP uses `awk` to isolate the first field. If so then `$0` will be too much.

Comment: oh that's right. I've used this with $0 to solve another problem, I guess I've got em mixed up. Sorry for stupid comment :)

Answer (score 3):

**1.** One pass with **`sed`**:

```
tail -3 newtag | sed "s/\(.*\)\s.*/'\1'/"
```

**Explanation:** in `sed` the replacement string does not have to be quoted

**2.** Or you could use **`perl`**:

```
tail -3 newtag | perl -anE "say qq('\$F[0]')"
```

**Explanation:**

- `perl` scripting language that excels at text processing
- `-a` split each line in fields
- `n` do not automatically print each line
- `E` execute the following command, and enable features such as `say`
- `"` start instructions with `"` because we later want to use `'`
- `say` print the following expression and a newline
- `qq(` start of literal expression that allows for variable interpolation
- `'` a literal `'`
- `\$F[0]` the first "field" on the line
- `'` a literal `'`
- `)` end of literal expression
- `"` end of instructions

Comment: `sed "s/^\(.*\)$/'\1'/"` works much better